# Decorator, why f will trigger the decorator instead of f()

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators

I am learning the decorator in python, and I don't understand why we should use f instead of f() to call the decorator. And somebody explain to me how "@deco" works, like why f itself without "()" will trigger the call.

```
def deco(f):
    print("This is dec function")
    print("Now execute f()")
    f()
@deco
def f():
    print("This is inside f()")

f()
```

Output:

```
   f()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

It works when I changed f() to f. Can somebody explain to me why

Comment: This provides a good explanation of how decorators work:   https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/decorator

Answer (score 0):

A decorator is basically syntax sugar for

```py
def f():
  [...]
f = deco(f)
```

So, as you have written it, `f` is `None` because `deco` does not return anything. You should probably add a wrapper, and return it, like this:

```py
def deco(f):
  def wrapper():
    print("This is the wrapper function")
    print("Calling f...")
    f()
  return wrapper

@deco
def f():
  print("This is inside f")
```

---

In your example, it "works" if you remove `()` simply because the call to `f` is made when the decorator is called, not at the `f()` line, which actually tries to call `None`. In your example, completely removing the last `f()` would still "work".